# Microsoft Teams | Is there a way to pin Configurable tab with team scope to left panel in Microsoft teams programmatically?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a Configurable tab with team scope in Microsoft Teams. One of our customers requested to pin the tab on the left panel.

Is there any way to achieve this programmatically?

Comment: Currently there is no way to pin tabs programmatically. You can use app setup policies to pin apps for users - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies#pin-apps. You can only pin static tabs as of now. See the app setup policy limitiations here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies#considerations-and-limitations